# How to provide access to a service account to read pods in multiple namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I'm going over RBAC in Kubernetes. It appears to me that

- a ServiceAccount can be bound to a Role within a namespace
  (or)
- a ServiceAccount can be bound to a ClusterRole and have cluster-wide access (all namespaces?)

Is it possible for a single Service Account (or User) to not have cluster-wide access but only have read-only access in only a subset of namespaces? If so, can someone elaborate on how this can be achieved. Thanks!

Comment: I think the solution is to define multiple `RoleBinding` for the one service account for each namespace in which you wish it permitted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a RoleBinding for every namespace in each namespace the ServiceAccount should have access to.

There is an example to give the default ServiceAccount permissions to read pods in the `development` namespace.

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-secrets
  namespace: development # This only grants permissions within the "development" namespace.
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```